# How to find what can be tuned in theme()

Tags: python, inspection, plotnine

New to python, I'm trying to fine tuning the plotnine graph, and explore what can be done in the theme() function. I'm just wondering what is the general way to find out what else is available for me to play with.

```
theme(plot_title = element_text(size=10, text='tile'), 
    axis_title_y = element_text(size=7, text='tlab'), 
    axis_title_x = element_text(size=7,text='xlab'))
```

Comment: Have you tried finding and reading the documentation?

Comment: Looks like the [docs](http://plotnine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/plotnine.themes.theme.html) don't say much, but most of the options seem to be based on the ones from [ggplot2](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html).

Comment: This is a example, but I’m looking for a more general approach of lookup for how how to use certain function method comprehensively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plotnine, they are called [themeables](http://plotnine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#Themeables).